# Is it allowed to modify the java.exe file

Tags: license, java

as in the title - is it allowed to modify the "Java.exe" and "javaw.exe" files? Like with Resource Hacker?

I want to change the executable icon but I am not sure if it is legit. I mean it is just some changes in the metadata - not the Java Code/functionality itself. That's why I am not sure.

The reason is because of the default java icon I can't get rid of in the Task Manager on Windows devices.

I use AdoptOpenJDK.

If it is not answerable easily at least some tips would be nice or anything I can look at except the licenses

Comment: An icon surely has little impact on whether you can remove a task or not from the list of running processes.

Comment: Also mind, if you start to modify the JDK, you are bound by the license, thus also you must indicate clearly in the distribution notes you changed it from the original.

Comment: @planetmaker FAOD, that applies if and only if the OP redistributes what (s)he's done.

Comment: That sure is true. But tbh, I can come up with more sinister reasons to change the icon and remove it from the list of visible processes than legit ones.

Comment: Ok so to wrap it up a little. OpenJDK is GPL-2+CE while AdoptOpenJDK's works are Apache 2.0 licensed. GPL-2 allows modifications but forces keep the same license. But this won't affect my "linked" work because the Classpath Exception allows it - am I right?

Comment: *In general*, it's legal to do *whatever the heck you want* on your own computer! As long as it doesn't hurt other people (e.g. hacking) or let you break copyright (DMCA has a special rule for this)

Answer (score 3):

I think it is legal since the AdoptOpenJDK jdk is open source. You don't even need to hack it, you can build it from it's [sources](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk).

To build is easy. Just follow the [instructions](https://github.com/AdoptOpenJDK/openjdk-jdk/blob/master/doc/building.md), but you will have to dig with the sources a little to find where to change the icon.